# Inputting an array as an initial guess in scipy's newton function

Tags: python, arrays, scipy

I am trying to use the newton function from scipy in a piece of code, and I would like to input an array as an initial guess. From scipy's website: [Scipy stating that newtons function can take an ndarray as an initial guess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqi7M.png)

The reason for this, is that in a complex nonlinear equation I am trying to solve, the newton function only works if the initial guess is close to the actual value, so I need to use an array of values that are close to the true values to get it to work. However, when I try to input an array as an initial guess via:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import newton

#Declaring frequency and wave vector arrays
w_array = np.linspace(0.1,3,1000)*10**15
k_array = np.array([])

#Declaring variables
p = 2.85*10**15
e1=1
c=300000000

def twolayer(k):
    e2 = 3.43-(p**2)/(w**2 - (1j*gamma*w))
    result = ((w/c)*(((e2*e1)/(e2+e1))**0.5))-k
    return result

#Loop that uses secant method for each value of omega to find solutions for k
for w in w_array:
    gamma = 2.23 * 10**14
    k_array = np.append(k_array,newton(twolayer,w_array[w]))

#Plotting
plt.figure(dpi=100)
plt.plot(k_array.real,w_array)
plt.xlabel('Wave vector k')
plt.ylabel('Frequency ω')
```

I get the following error:

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Any ideas on how i can get this to work?

Comment: For the record, in this code, I am just trying to get the array to work as an initial guess, this is not actually the code I would be using as a better guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
for w in w_array:
    gamma = 2.23 * 10**14
    k_array = np.append(k_array,newton(twolayer,w)
```

Instead of

```
for w in w_array:
    gamma = 2.23 * 10**14
    k_array = np.append(k_array,newton(twolayer,w_array[w]))
```

Comment: Oh sorry! That's my bad, I was just trying to get the function to work with an array in this case. I actually need to implement a different array from the w_array!

Comment: No need!! we are here to help :)